# dplyr group by muliple columns does not terminate

Tags: r, dplyr

When I just calculate count after grouping, it works perfectly. Below is the code:

```
monthly <- stocks %>%
           group_by(stocks$x, stocks$y) %>%
           summarize(value = n())
```

But when I use any other stats method such as mean or sum. It does not terminate.

```
monthly <- stocks %>%
           group_by(stocks$x, stocks$y) %>%
           summarize(value = mean(stocks$z))
```

Is there any other library to do this in R? 
I need summary of z after multiple grouping (x, y).

Comment: You don't need `stocks$x`, stocks$y` inside group_by or `summarize`.  Just do `stocks %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(value = n())`

Comment: Try `monthly <- stocks %>%    group_by(x, y) %>%  summarize(value = mean(z))`

Comment: You saved my time.Thank you so much, It worked!